# Adding the images to the Asp dot net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to to insert a logo into the navbar. But it is not loading properly.
I don't know why the src  of image not going to that file path.

Here is the code for the CsHtml File :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" style="background-color:#249116;">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="../logo.png" />
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="EquipmentMasterModels" asp-action="Index" style="margin-left:10%;">SpireViews</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="font-weight-bolder text-center text-light">
                    Communication Channel
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Here is my folder structure in dot net :

[image: Folder Structure For the Reference.]

Here is the Error Message Shown in the console of the browser : 
[image: Image for the Error in browser.]

Comment: Please share the properties of the image. What is the 'Build Action' and 'Copy to Output Directory' properties?

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the view is `_Layout`

Comment: Go to the Network Tab and see the full URL of the image that it's trying to load. You might have to make the src `../../logo.png` or `../Views/logo.png`

Comment: Check the path of your image (on build time, so the entire path) and then route to that path manually to see if the picture exists. I think it refers to the map "Shared" and it does not contain an image named "logo".

Answer (score 0):

Move your logo.png into wwwroot folder and use ~/logo.png, because ASP.NET Core gets static files from only wwwroot folder.

Comment: But OP is using ASP.NET-MVC. Not Core

Comment: Probably, as per project folder structure, its look like ASP.NET Core, but He had a mistake on question writing.

Comment: I agree. There is no wwwroot folder by default in ASP.NET-MVC , there is in Core though, and the image he uploaded it seems like a .NET Core project. Also, no asp-area or asp-controller in .cshtml trasitional MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you have designated it in a higher folder than where it is '' much better  to place images in an /Images folder and refer to it as                 . Do not forget that files in the Views folder are not referred to as /Views, they are implicitly in the application's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your application in MVC there will be a folder Content. In that folder create a folder of your preference, I use IMG.

When you create the image in yourpage.cshtml format do:

img src="../Content/IMG/image.png" . do not forget<>..

That will make it work. You do not have to create an images folder in the inetpub root directory.

DroidRiot C# Programmer